# Diagnostic Logs (Storage) not showing up in Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Im using services such as on prem data gateway, logic apps, etc, and I've configured diagnostics on these instances to send logs to both Log Analytics and Storage.
I go to the storage account, and I see zero log files.
I go to containers --> its empty
I go to tables --> its empty.

I really need to see the logs. What do i do?

Comment: Can you provide what your log settings look like and what log types are enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are something you need to check.

1.There is a latency for the logs to take effect. Please wait a few minutes, then check if the logs are stored in blob storage.

2.Please check your Diagnostics settings, if you have configured everything correctly. Like you choose the log type and metrics.

3.Make sure you check the logs in the blob storage which you configured in your Diagnostics settings.